# Query appearing in the url react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm making an app on React using HashRouter. In the app I have a form with inputs and after user submit data, some of the data appears in the URL like that:

http://localhost:3000/?State=Alabama#/profile

When it's supposed to be just

http://localhost:3000/#/profile

Function on submit button is just taking all the values and sending to the database like that:

```
    handleSubmit() {
        const { userUrl } = this.props;
        let { street_address, state, city, zip, email, phone, avatar, about_message, proximity } = this.state;

        if (this.props.user.title === 'caregiver') {
            axios.put('/update/profile', {
                street_address,
                state,
                city,
                zip,
                email,
                phone,
                avatar: userUrl.length ? userUrl : avatar,
                about_message,
                proximity
            })
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                    this.setState({
                        street_address,
                        state,
                        city,
                        zip,
                        email,
                        phone,
                        avatar,
                        about_message,
                        proximity
                    })
                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error))
        }
    }
```

I figured out the problem is partially in the form because some of the inputs have name="" attribute and if I take it out it won't show in the URL. But the question mark is still showing up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to prevent the form for doing the default submission :

```
handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        const { userUrl } = this.props;
        let { street_address, state, city, zip, email, phone, avatar, about_message, proximity } = this.state;

        if (this.props.user.title === 'caregiver') {
            axios.put('/update/profile', {
                street_address,
                state,
                city,
                zip,
                email,
                phone,
                avatar: userUrl.length ? userUrl : avatar,
                about_message,
                proximity
            })
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response);
                    this.setState({
                        street_address,
                        state,
                        city,
                        zip,
                        email,
                        phone,
                        avatar,
                        about_message,
                        proximity
                    })
                })
                .catch(error => console.log(error))
        }
    }
```